# How find this sum $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\frac{n+1}{(2n+1)!}$

Tags: summation

Find this follow sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}\dfrac{n+1}{(2n+1)!}$$

My try:since
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{n+1}{(2n+1)!}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{2n+1+1}{(2n+1)!}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{1}{(2n)!}+\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)!}=\dfrac{1}{2}[\cos{1}+\sin{1}]$$

My question: have other methods? Thank you

Comment: Your method is good. I don't think you'll find a better one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$e^y=\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{y^r}{r!}$$

and
$$e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x,e^{-ix}=\cos x-i\sin x\implies e^{ix}\pm e^{-ix}=?$$

Now, 
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{1}{(2n)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{i^{2n}}{(2n)!}=2(e^i+e^{-i})$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)!}=\frac1i\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}i^{2n+1}\dfrac{1}{(2n+1)!}=\frac{2(e^i-e^{-i})}i=-2i(e^i-e^{-i})$$